# Using ViewScript Decorator on Nested Subforms (Zend Form)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-sub-form

I want to use a view script to render my zend form as it seems to be the best way to 
control the layout/design of the form while still using the Zend_Elements classes.

From the view script, I render the element with `$this->element->getElement('elementName')` .

I'm having problems with the names of the elements. This is actually a sub-form inside a sub-form inside a form.

When I used the FormElements decorators , the fully qualified name of the elements was form[subForm][subForm][element] , which was good.
Wehn I moved to the viewScript decorators, it changed to subForm[subForm][element].

I understood that I need to use the PrepareElements decorator to fix this, but this caused the name to change form[subForm][form][subForm][subForm][elements] (it doubled the first two names in the start).

Any ideas how I should handle this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I tried to debug PrepareElements and I really don't understand what is doing.
It seems like it works ok in the first iteration, but then it adds again the form[subform] prefix when running on one of the middle subforms.

When I'm not using the PrepareElements decorator, I'm just missing the "form" prefix in the names (i.e., instead of form[subForm][element], I get only subForm[element]).

May be I can just fix this somehow?

I tried to change the belongsTo but that only replaced the "subForm" prefix .

It actually seems like what is missing is a belongsTo method on the subForm.

Again, this is all because of the ViewScript decorator. It works fine with the FormElements decorators.

**UPDATE 2:** Just to clarify, I wouldn't mind this name change, but it causes my fields to not populate when I call form->populate .

**Edit:** I think that I've narrowed the problem to this: when I get my values back in setDefaults, they are ordered like this:

```
array(
\"formElements1-name\" => value1... \"subFormName\" => array(
\"parentFormName\" => array(
\"subFormName\" => subForm-values-array
)
)
```

...
The main problem here is the `"parentFormName" => "subFormNAme"..` what does it repeat itself? I'm already in the main form. I'm guessing this is caused because I've set the `setElementsBelongTo(formName[subFormName])` , but if I wouldn't do that, then I would get my subform values completely separate from the form,

i.e. 
    values array = array(
    \"formName\" => array(
    formValues
    ), \"subFormNAme\" => array(
    subFormValues
    )

, while I exepct it to be

```
array(
formName => array(
subFormNAme => values-array
)
)...
```

Is it even possible to make this work?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Zend: ViewScript decorator and array notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155047/zend-viewscript-decorator-and-array-notation)

Comment: It's not a duplicate since I'm already using the suggested solutions but it doesn't work well.

Comment: Zend forms has to be the most broken, ridiculous, insane piece of crap I've ever had the misfortune to be subjected to.  I totally feel your pain, if you figure out what's wrong then by all means please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current solution is to use the PrepareElements decorator on the subforms with one change - remove the recursive call in the PrepareElements code. Also, no "setElementsBelongTo" is required.

This seem to generate the correct names and ids.

Comment: Did you modify PrepareElements.php of Zend?

Answer (score 8):

Are you just trying to output your form using `<?php echo $this->form; ?>` from your view script?

That works well for simple forms, but for my more complex forms I tend to render each element individually but don't need to use ViewScript decorator on each individual element to do this.  Just try something like this from your view script:

```
<div class="form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Some Form Name</legend>
        <form action="<?php echo $this->escape($this->form->getAction()) ?>"
              method="<?php echo $this->escape($this->form->getMethod()) ?>"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <?php echo $this->form->id; // render the id element here ?>

            <div class="half">
                <?php echo $this->form->name; // render the user name field here ?>
            </div>
            <div class="half">
                <?php echo $this->form->description; // render the description element here ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="half">
                <?php echo $this->form->address1; // render the address ?>
            </div>
            <div class="half">
                <?php echo $this->form->address2; // render address2 ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="third">
                <?php echo $this->form->zip; // render zip code ?>
            </div>
            <div class="third">
                <?php echo $this->form->city; // render city ?>
            </div>
            <div class="third">
                <?php echo $this->form->state; // render state ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="half">
                <?php echo $this->form->country; // render country ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <?php echo $this->form->submit; ?>

        </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

That is how I do most of my forms because I want to have some elements take up half the width and others the full width.

Surprisingly, the reference guide doesn't tell you that you can do this.  I seem to remember a page about it in the past but cannot find it now.  When I got started with Zend Framework, I thought the only way I could get my form to output exactly how I wanted was to create complex decorators, but that is not the case.

Matthew Weier O'Phinney has a great blog post on [rendering Zend_Form decorators individually](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/215-Rendering-Zend_Form-decorators-individually.html) which explains what I did above.  I hope they add this to the first page of Zend Form because that was discouraging to me at first.  The fact is, 90% of my forms render elements individually instead of just echo'ing the form itself.

Note: To stop ZF from enclosing my form elements in the dt and dd tags, I apply this decorator to all of my standard form elements.  I have a base form class that I extend all of my forms from so I don't have to repeat this everywhere.  This is the decorator for the element so I can use  tags to enclose my elements.

```
public $elementDecorators = array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    array('Description', array('tag' => 'p',    'class' => 'description')),
    array('HtmlTag',     array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'form-div')),
    array('Label',       array('class' => 'form-label', 'requiredSuffix' => '*'))
);
```

For my submit buttons I use

```
public $buttonDecorators = array(
    'ViewHelper',
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'form-button'))
);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do, only with sub-forms . The problem is that the generated names of the sub form elements are wrong when I use the ViewScript decorator.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to use the `belongsTo()` form element property.
Example :

```
new Zend_Form_Element_Text('<elementName>', array('belongsTo' => '<subformName>'))
```

In this way, the render() method will use a form element name like

```
name="<subformName>[<elementName>]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved it with a decorator

1 : Create a generic subform with elements

2 : Using a specific decorator with PrepareElements

3 : Change form to an array with setIsArray(true)

Example :

Form

```
$i = 4;
for($i = 0; $i < $nbReclam ; $i++)
{
    $rowForm = new Zend_Form_SubForm($i);
    $name= new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('name');
    $rowForm->addElement($name);
    $this->addSubForm($rowForm, $i);
}

$this->setDecorators(array(
            'PrepareElements',
            array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'myDecorator.phtml')),
    ));   


$this->setIsArray(true);
```

Decorator

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>N°</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($this->element->getSubForms() as $subForm) : ?>
            <tr>
               <td> <?php echo $i++?> </td>
               <?php foreach ($subForm->getElements() as $row) : ?>
                   <td><?php echo $row ?></td>
               <?php endforeach ?>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Enjoy

Sorry for my english, i am french