# Customizing a form using Zend_Form_Decorator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

How can I customize my form using Zend_Form_Decorator? And how can I add a paragraph inside the form? It is just so difficult to do some simple things using Zend_Form :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not technically the same question, something very similar was asked not long ago: [Using ViewScript Decorator on Nested Subforms (Zend Form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589603/using-viewscript-decorator-on-zend-form)

You can get many interesting links in the answers, that can help you to get started with decorators. For instance, if you want to add some markup inside the form, you could render the elements separately (details and links in the above question).

Hope that helps,