# unable to render Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

i'm trying to render a login form using Zend_Form, i want it to be rendered calling www.site.com/login or www.site.com/account/login, but once i've done all the steps below and i try to call /login or /account/login from my browser i'm getting a HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error).. even if the rest of the site works perfectly. Please help me figure out where i'm wrong..

(note that I'm using Zend Framework 1.11)

(1) Create the model through ZF

> zf create model FormLogin

(2) Edit the new created model in application/models/FormLogin.php

```
class Application_Model_FormLogin extends Zend_Form
{
     public function __construct($options = null)
    {

         parent::__construct($options);

         $this->setName('login');
         $this->setMethod('post'); // GET O POST

         $this->setAction('/account/login'); // form action=[..]

         $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
         $email->setAttrib('size', 35);

         $pswd = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('pswd');
         $pswd->setAttrib('size', 35);

         $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit'); // submit button

         $this->setDecorators( array( array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => '_form_login.phtml'))));
         $this->addElements(array($email, $pswd, $submit));

       } 

}
```

(3) Add loginAction to the Account controller

```
class AccountController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

    public function loginAction()
    {
        $form = new Application_Model_FormLogin();

          $this->view->form = $form;

    }


}
```

(4) Create the View at application/views/scripts/account/login.phtml

> ```
> <?php echo $this->form; ?>
> ```

(5) Create the page application/views/scripts/_form_login.phtml called by setDecorators() at the point (2)

```
<form id="login" action="<?php echo $this->element->getAction(); ?>"
method="<?php echo $this->element->getMethod(); ?>">
<p>
    E-mail Address<br />
    <?php echo $this->element->email; ?>
</p>
<p>
    Password<br />
    <?php echo $this->element->pswd; ?>
</p>
<p>
    <?php echo $this->element->submit; ?>
</p>
</form>
```

(6) And this is my Bootstrap.php

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    public function _initRoutes()
    {

        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $router = $frontController->getRouter();


        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static (
            'login',
            array('controller' => 'Account', 'action' => 'login')
        );

        $router->addRoute('login', $route);

        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route (
            'games/asin/:asin/',
            array('controller' => 'Games',
                  'action'     => 'view',
                   'asin'       => 'B000TG530M' // default value
                 )
        );
        $router->addRoute('game-asin-view', $route);



    }
}
```

Comment: I think you do not require to define any route for default module's `controller/action`.

Comment: It doesn't work even if I remove my routes

Comment: It should work, as the error says, it's an "Internal Server Error", nothing wrong with your code to me.

Comment: Take a look at your Apache error log to see what the error actually is

Comment: See this answer for one way to render your form elements individually WITHOUT having to do the viewscript decorator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589603/using-viewscript-decorator-on-nested-subforms-zend-form/7590262#7590262

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your class definition for `Application_Model_FormLogin` to the following:

```
<?php

class Application_Model_FormLogin extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('login');
        $this->setMethod('post'); // GET O POST

        $this->setAction('/account/login'); // form action=[..]

        $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
        $email->setAttrib('size', 35);

        $pswd = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('pswd');
        $pswd->setAttrib('size', 35);

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit'); // submit button

        $this->setDecorators( array( array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => '_form_login.phtml'))));
        $this->addElements(array($email, $pswd, $submit));
    }
}
```

You should set your form up using the `init()` method rather than using `__construct()`

When you call `parent::__construct($options);` in the constructor for your `Zend_Form`, that ends up calling the form's `init()` method and then nothing after that is executed so your form initialization and element creation was never being called.

The 500 internal server was because you were calling `parent::__construct()` and your form had no `init()` method.

Comment: $this->element is correct when using the viewScript decorator. $this->form is correct when using $this->render(veiwScript)

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice it was being used in a view script decorator.  I figured since it was rendering the full form that the view code was just in the view script.  I removed that part now.

Comment: Your solution worked, thank you.
But now it revealed another problem,  Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_FormLogin' not found in application\controllers\AccountController.php on line 18

so basically Zend don't load my FormLogin.php model, how can I load it? i think i'm missing something in the bootstrap.. thank you again

Comment: If you are using Zend Application, the autoloader should be set up to find that file automatically.  Make sure your directory structure follows the [recommended project structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.project.html).  On a slightly unrelated note, since that class is a form, you may want to move it into the `forms` directory and rename the class to `Application_Form_Login`.  It may fix the problem, but when you create a model, it sounds like that will fail to load.

Answer (score 1):

**drew010** has a good point about setting up your form in `init()` rather then`__construct()`.

I just spent hours fighting with the viewScript method and this is how I got it to work (so far).

- `$this->view->form = $form` assigns to the view
- then in your view you need to render the partial with something like
   `<?php echo $this->render('_form_login.phtml')`
- if you use this method then you access your elements using
   `<?php echo $this->form->email; ?>`
- Using this method I did not use the `$this->setDecorators( array( array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => '_form_login.phtml'))));` line of code.

The proper way to do this uses the viewScript decorator, however I have not been able to make it work yet. I did find that using this decorator I had to access the elements using `$this->element->elementname`, but I could not find anyway to access the method or action. `getMethod()` and `getAction()` both returned errors.

[EDIT]
ok i got it to work:

- Make your form as normal using `init()`
- `$form->setDecorators(array(
          array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => '_yourScript.phtml'))
      ));` I like to add this in the controller.
- in your viewScript access the form object using `$this->element` instead of `$this->form`
- assign your form to the view normally `$this->view->form = $form`
- render the form normally `<?php echo $this->form ?>`

this is the example I got to work...finally

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->element->getAction() ?>"
      method="<?php echo $this->element->getMethod() ?>">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $this->element->weekend->renderLabel() ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->element->weekend->renderViewHelper() ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->element->bidlocation->renderLabel() ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->element->bidlocation->renderViewHelper() ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->element->shift->renderLabel() ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->element->shift->renderViewHelper() ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6"><?php echo $this->element->submit ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I think my hoof-in-mouth is cured for the moment.