# Zend subform view script render

Tags: html, forms, zend-framework

I would rather not deal with decorators as my form design is not exactly straight forward, but i would like to keep the functionality of validating the forms.

So i have it set up where sub forms are working correctly, but when i try to style it manually in my viewscript i get the name without the parent. I've seen other posts that are similar, but i haven't found a solution.

Example:

This is in my view script

`<?php echo $this->form->username->renderViewHelper();?>`

I then get

`<input type="text" value="" id="username" name="username">`

When rendered. It should be

`<input type="text" value="" id="form1-username" name="form1[username]">`

How do i get that form1 portion?

Thanks!

---

## Edit

Ok, so i found one way.

By using belongTo, it works:

```
    $form1->addElements(array(
        new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username', array(
            'belongsTo' => 'form1',
            'required'   => true,
            'label'      => 'Username:',
            'filters'    => array('StringTrim', 'StringToLower'),
            'validators' => array(
                'Alnum',
                array('Regex',
                      false,
                      array('/^[a-z][a-z0-9]{2,}$/'))
            )
        ))
     ));
```

Is there a better way to do this or is this the only way?

---

## Edit2

```
public function prepareSubForm($spec){
    if (is_string($spec)) {
        $subForm = $this->{$spec};
    } elseif ($spec instanceof Zend_Form_SubForm) {
        $subForm = $spec;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Invalid argument passed to ' .
                            __FUNCTION__ . '()');
    }
    $this->setSubFormDecorators($subForm)
         ->addSubmitButton($subForm)
         ->addSubFormActions($subForm);
    return $subForm;
}

public function setSubFormDecorators(Zend_Form_SubForm $subForm){
    $subForm->setDecorators(array(
        'FormElements', \\<--- I tried to change this to PrepareElements before.
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dl',
                               'class' => 'zend_form')),
        'Form',
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the [`PrepareElements`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.prepareElements) decorator for the form?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Zend: ViewScript decorator and array notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155047/zend-viewscript-decorator-and-array-notation). This is the second question on this topic posted in the last couple of hours, weird

Comment: @fireeyedboy no, ill update my post with what i am using. I'm new with Zend, so i don't know how decorators even work right now.

Comment: @Phil not quite, i don't have an array of elements. It's just one text box for right now. But it doesn't add the parent form name, which it needs for validation.

Comment: @Matt The answer (as indicated by fireeyedboy) is the same

Comment: @Phil either way, it's not working, not sure why. I tried to add that in there and it just isn't adding that parent name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can get your desired output just by using:

```
<?php echo $this->form->username; ?>
```

I get the expected output when calling this without renderViewHelper.  This is also without any special code for decorators or preparing sub forms.  All I had to do was add `belongsTo` to the form element.

UPDATED:

If you set this to be your default decorator, you can eliminate the dd/dt tags from rendering, instead it will use a div.  Then you may be closer to getting the custom output you want.  You can change the `tag` in `HtmlTag` from `div` to whatever tag you would like to wrap your elements in.  This is what I use mostly:

```
array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    array('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'description')),
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'form-div')),
    array('Label', array('class' => 'form-label', 'requiredSuffix' => '*'))
);
```

This is the default for Zend Framework:

```
array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    array('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'description')),
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd', 'id' => array('callback' => $getId)))
    array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt'))
);
```

Note that file, and submit/button elements use different decorators.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589603/using-viewscript-decorator-on-zend-form/7590262#7590262)

Comment: if i do the default render like that i get the dt/dd tags, which i obviously don't want if i want to do it manually. But yea, as stated in my edits, i can do that if i do belongsTo, but i can't get it work with PrepareElements.

Comment: yea it still wraps all the elements in dd/dt tags, but it wraps all the elements in a container div with the class form-div. So i don't know. Like i said, i have no clue how these decorators even work.